# How to add a custom scrollbar to gnome taskbar?

Tags: gnome

I need to add a simple scrollbar (vertical or horizontal, it doesn't matter) to gnome taskbar, to pass an argument to a program I'm writing.
Just to be clear enough, something very much like volume control.
In fact this is for screen brightness, because the builtin scrollbar doesn't work on my laptop.

Of course I will share my work if someone needs such utility.

Thank you!